# blank part in the contour plot

Tags: plotting

Why did my listcontourplot have some blank part like the below?
I've checked that my data is in the range of [2.5, 4].
Is it because that it changes so fast??
[image]

Comment: try `PlotRange->Full`

Comment: Or `PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: Yes, it is the same question as mine. Thank you! @Szabolcs